# React - Returning data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I know there are similar questions, but I can't find the answer.

First, please tell me if I'm doing something really wrong

I need to populate my state with data from an API call. This was working fine with code above:

```
export const GetPlanets = async () => {

    const planets = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`).catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        })

  return planets.data.results
}
```

But then I needed to make a second call to several links from one json response filed, and I managed to make it work (don't know if it is the correct approach, though)

```
const GetPlanets = async () => {
    let planetas = {}

   await axios.get(`${PLANETS_URL}`)
    .then((p) => {

        planetas = p.data.results

        return axios.get(`${FILMS_URL}`)
    }).then((f) => {

   planetas.films.forEach((v, i) => {
              planetas[i].film = f
        })
     })

        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(e);
        })

    return planetas
}
```

This is my component file, where I try to get the object, like I was doing before

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPlanetas = async () => {  // ME TRYING...
      const planetas = await GetPlanets()
      setPlanetas(planetas)
      setToShow(planetas[0])
    };
    fetchPlanetas()
  }, [])
```

But all I get is undefined

[image]

Comment: In your first code block you assign the result of the data fetch to a `const` called `planets`, but then return `planetas.data.results`, but `planetas` is not declared in that scope.  I'm assuming that that is a typo?  If not, it is a likely clue as to the issues you are seeing...

Comment: yes, it's a typo, I'm not using this code anymore

Comment: firstly, I'd recommend migrating to fetch, and the whatwg-fetch polyfill. there's not really a need for axios or any other libraries that try to figure out the mess that is `AJAX` any more. **especially** if you're using ES6 concepts like `const` and `let`

Comment: with `fetch` json is as simple as `const response = await fetch('my_url'); const result = await response.json()`

Comment: a teacher said axios is being largely used by companies (at least in my country), that's why I'm using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an array of `undefined` because `.map()` needs a return value. In both your `.map()` callbacks, you are not returning anything.

```js
const results = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const results2 = results.map(elem => {
    elem = elem + 1
})
console.log(results2)
```

But, even if you did return something in your `.map()` callback, `GetFilms(f)` is asynchronous, so you would not get the results of `GetFilms()` mapped into the array as you would expect.

You have a couple of options:

1. If you have access to the API, send the films data along with the rest of the data when you do your first request.
2. Use `async/await` and `Promise.all()` to get responses.

Comment: so, there is no way I can "append" films to planets response/object like I'm trying?

Comment: I am unsure what you desired output is and what you data structure looks like, but I'm sure there is a way to solve this.

Comment: yes, it works now, I updated the question. thank you